# induction mathematics in bracket of quantum group

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, quantum-groups, groebner-generators

By the induction mathematics .
How can prove the following [fm,f1m]=0,where f is generators in quantum group and m greter than 3.

Comment: algebra-precalculus and quantum groups? That might be a first. Can you please give more context to your question, and also use mathjax to format your formulas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of this prove we can not used the second step which is
[fm,f1m]=0 in prove final step which is induction step.